# Travelling to Singapore via BKK

Tags: visas, transit, bkk

I have an emergency here. My friend is traveling to Singapore at the moment , and was held at the airport transit area (he is an Armenia citizen btw)by immigration for he doesnt hold a transit visa which he hadnt been told by anyone before as traveling thru transit flights usually do not require any visas. So can any one suggest what to do here pls... Any suggestion maybe will help.

Comment: If your friend is being held by the authorities he will have to do what they instruct him to do. He might just be put in a plane back to where he came from. He might be fined, or charged. If he's put on a plane his best option is probably just to accept it and go. Anything else and he should consider asking for a lawyer. [Travel.se] is not a good place for advice on this sort of issue.

Comment: A quick check on the web site of a [Thai Embassy](http://www.thaiembassy.org/telaviv/en/services/685/17388-Entry-to-Thailand.html) suggests that your friend is correct in believing he didn't need a transit visa. Something more is going on here.

Comment: Transit without visa doesn't apply when flying low-cost carriers into and out of Bangkok (and most other places) because you have to clear immigration in and out to change flights on these carriers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not if you check-in online and have no luggage, but we're well into speculation here...